# How can I get a string from the contents of a photograph on android?

Tags: android

I am making an application for android as a final project in a class. The application determines if the equation is written a line, circle, ellipse, parabola or hyperbola. Now I can do it if I typed in the equation. Now what you are asking me is to take a photograph of the equation and make all the calculations automatically. Could you help? I know it's possible but have not found a single reference to indicate how. Really please that I only need to complete.

Answer (score 0):

You need an OCR (optical character recognition) library. I suggest you look into that. For example, look at [this](http://metaoptimize.com/qa/questions/2097/ocr-lib-for-math-formulas) post.